# Meteor Restivus: Error Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to use [Restivus](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus) to expose a get route to return a specific document by its serial number.

Basic code:

```
// lib/router.js
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {
  except: ['auth', 'api']
});

// server/restivus.js
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Restivus.configure({
    useAuth: false,
    prettyJson: true
  });
});

// lib/collection/schedule.js

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Restivus.addRoute('schedules/:serial', {authRequired: false}, {
    get: function() {
      var schedule = Schedules.findOne({collector: this.urlParams.serial});
      if (schedule) {
        return {status: 'success', data: schedule};
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Complete log error:

curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/schedules/00000020

```
Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.
    at Object.Meteor.userId (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:19:1)
    at [object Object].requireLogin (app/lib/router.js:85:15)
    at packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:277:1
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
    at [object Object].hookWithOptions (packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:276:1)
    at boundNext (packages/iron:middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1)
    at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
    at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:121:1
    at [object Object].dispatch (packages/iron:middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:275:1)
    at [object Object].RouteController._runRoute (packages/iron:router/lib/route_controller_server.js:63:1)
```

Comment: Source: https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/issues/40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved adding !Meteor.isServer at hook onBeforeAction:

```
var requireLogin = function() {
  if (!Meteor.isServer && !Meteor.userId() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
    this.redirect('auth');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {
  except: ['auth']
});
```